# How to change throughput units in jmeter?

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

In my **jmeter summary report** my throughput is coming in **/min**.
I want to change it to **/sec**

Answer (score 0):

[Summary Report](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Summary_Report)'s Throughput is displayed according to measurements, if your response are in seconds or milliseconds, see below example:

> Throughput - the Throughput is measured in requests per second/minute/hour. The time unit is chosen so that the displayed rate is at least 1.0. When the throughput is saved to a CSV file, it is expressed in requests/second, i.e. 30.0 requests/minute is saved as 0.5.

[image]

Comment: When I am saving the summary report in .csv file throughput valus are not coming

Comment: @paulpo CSV holds transactions and not summary, you can load csv by Browse to summary report

Comment: you can load .csv file in Aggregate Report then Throughput can be check from there